# center img within div

Tags: javascript, html, extjs

I have a container in a sencha extjs app, with an img div inside it, on the left side of the container. I want it centered so rotation works out (because I'm already fitting the image to its longest dimension).

```
<div class="x-component ih-image-container x-box-item x-component-default"
    style="width: 516px; overflow: auto !important; right: auto; left: 0px; margin: 0px; top: 30px; height: 429px;" 
    id="component-1990">

    <img class="ih-image" 
        style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%; border-left: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out 0s; transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1); width: auto;" 
        src="/viewer/image/urlabridged" data-rotate="0" data-scale="1">
</div>
```

I have tried adding each of these to no effect, from similar questions on SO

> vertical-align: middle; 
>   text-align: center; 
>   display: block

It is possible that other extjs containers which contain these are changing things.

Comment: Add float: left; text-align: center; to div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use HTML `<center>` tag?

```css
.rotate90 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(30deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(30deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(30deg);
    transform: rotate(30deg);
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 516px; overflow: auto !important; right: auto; left: 0px; margin: 0px; top: 30px; height: 429px; background-color:red;">
<center><img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/ad942ab5a7f58014ab966ae26cb91f87?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" class="rotate90"/></center>
</div>
```

Comment: Works ... technically <center> is deprecated, but this also works with an intermediate <div style="text-align: center; height: 100%; width: 100%"> where you have center. Odd that it wouldn't work on the actual containing div.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `margin: auto;`?
Also you can use flex for outer component:

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
```

Also, if your outer component has fixed size and `position: relative`, then you can use

```
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
```

Comment: translateX/Y is looking promising. It's not really playing nice with the rotate, but it's a lot better than it was before, so I'll accept it as the answer to the limited question I was able to pose. Thank you.

Comment: @KennyOstrom maybe playing with `transform-origin` will help you with rotating problem?

Comment: adding a <center> element worked better, so this was helpful +1, but I needed different translations for each rotation, and it doesn't generalize well to oddly shaped images.

Comment: @KennyOstrom <center> tag is deprecated and should not be used: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_center.asp

Comment: It works with an intermediate <div> replacing <center>.